# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop no display suddenly "can't open display"

Tags: ssh, display, ubuntu-22.04

Summarize the problem:

I have a headless homeserver running ubuntu-desktop 22.04 using an HDMI dummy plug and have been working fine for months. but lately when remoting using "rustdesk" I keep getting an error "can't open display".

it haven't been rebooted by the time it was throwing this error, and rebooting it doesn't help at all. my family have confirmed connecting it to a monitor that it does display on boot (in uefi) and on ubuntu recovery mode. but after entering the normal ubuntu os the screen stays black, but i can ssh to the server (so it boots).

running the command "xrandr --query" throws the same error "Cant Open Display"
i have tried updating the Nvidia driver. it was running nvidia-smi 535 before now its 545.
i have tried runing "apt update and upgrade" and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop to no luck. i m pretty sure this is some software issue.

i have tried to run
"sudo get-edid | parse-edid"
it returns:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Problem requesting slave address: Device or resource busy
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
1 potential busses found: 2
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 2
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "28E850"
        ModelName "28E850"
        VendorName "AOC"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 3 of 2017
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 620 340
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "true"
        #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 75Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 61Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1200, 60Hz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 97)
#DOUBLE WARNING: It's your first mode, too, so this may actually be important.
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 63)
#DOUBLE WARNING: It's your first mode, too, so this may actually be important.
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 96)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 101)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 102)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 93)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 94)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 95)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 98)
        Modeline        "Mode 3" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1083 1088 1125 +hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 268.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1600 1603 1609 1646 +hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 2" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1449 1481 +hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 4" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 6" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 7" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 8" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 9" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 10" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 11" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 12" 336.72 2880 2928 2960 3040 1800 1803 1809 1846 +hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 13" 297.00 3840 3888 3920 4400 2160 2164 2170 2250 +hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 14" 594.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2162 2172 2250 +hsync +vsync
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 3"
EndSection
```

after reading the article here: https://goughlui.com/2019/06/02/review-teardown-generic-hdmi-cheater-dummy-plug-4k-uhd/
it seems to bedetected by the read-edid but not ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Check for broken packages and fix them. Then perform a full Ubuntu update.

- To fix packages via GUI, use the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-broken-packages-on-ubuntu/).
- To fix them [by command line](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages), a bit more involved but a bit more thorough, enter the following in succession, waiting for each to complete:

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to open *Terminal*.
  - `sudo apt update --fix-missing`
  - `sudo apt install -f`
  - `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
  - `sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..R`  [This lists packages that must be reinstalled.]
  - Apply `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all <package-name>` to remove *each* bad package listed in the previous query.
  - After forcing removal of bad packages, `sudo apt clean`.
  - And again, `sudo apt update` to reinstall packages after removing bad packages.

BTW, here's a small shell script that I run periodically to keep Ubuntu up-to-date:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
sudo apt -y autoremove --purge
```

Note that it *does not* update SNAP components, since I've removed SNAP completely.

Comment: i have tried this, all my app is up to date. is it possible the display goes to sleep? and now its not detecting the display at all? since most of the time I'm not running any 3D apps on the PC and just remote it using ssh.

Comment: Good point -- most displays have an energy-saving feature and shut off without signal. Is there a setting for the time which the Ubuntu display handler tries to connect to the device, after Ubuntu resumes? Perhaps that can be extended. Alternatively, set the display to be mirrored across two devices, one of which stays on, if you can.

Comment: hmm, I don't think it's possible to wake the display remotely... I guess I need someone to wake the monitor up. I'm on the other side of the world hahaha...